# Finding $a$ and $b$ using derivatives

Tags: calculus

I am having a bit of trouble with this question: Suppose $f(x)=(2x-b)^a$. Find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that $f'(x)=24x^2-24x+6$

One way I tried doing this is by equating the derivative of $f(x)$ to the quadratic. The derivative of $f(x)$ would be $a[(2x-b)^{a-1}](2)$. But I am unsure where to go from here. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have a second order polynomial in the derivative, so you can assume that $a-1=2,$ then use the expansion $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2.$

Comment: b = 1 and a = 3 :)

Comment: Wow awesome, I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thank you so much!!!! I love solving math questions on my spare and I love those aha moments when you get it. Thanks!

Comment: I was wondering if anyone could provide some hints to solve these ones as well?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175223/first-principle-derivative-question

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=(2x-b)^a$

$f'(x)=2a(2x-b)^{a-1}$

$f'(x)=24x^2-24x+6=6(4x^2-4x+1)=6(2x-1)^2$

$a-1=2, b=1$

Comment: Thank you!! I would love to know how to do these as well! Any tips would help. thanks! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175223/first-principle-derivative-question